# Nested for loop in windows 10 command prompt error

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt

I am trying to get only one column from task list command in cmd prompt using below

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (`netstat -ano ^|findstr /R /C:"\<:9000\>"`) DO FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %z IN (`tasklist /fi "pid eq %i"  /fi "services ne MSSQLSERVER" ^|findstr "%i"`) do @echo %z
```

I am unable to figure out whats missing in my above command. I see a part of command as output instead of seeing the first column of tasklist output..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing **@** before second FOR and my **tokens** in the second for loop was wrong.

Following worked out for me. Hope it helps others

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (`netstat -ano ^|findstr /R /C:"\<:9000\>"`) DO @FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %z IN (`tasklist /fi "pid eq %i"  /fi "services ne MSSQLSERVER" ^|findstr "%i"`) do @echo %z
```